# Website crashes at simple repeated AJAX / JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am developing a simple tool as a project and I am having some issues with the website crashing when the AJAX part of my website is requested/used to many times in a row.

I have a bunch of text fields, and when the user enters into any of them, I want to the test to be typed out automatically below the input field. For example if the user types "test1" Into the first field, and "test2" into the second, I want "test1 test2" to dynamically output below without the page refreshing. I know how to do this in PHP however I need to use AJAX or JQUERY so the page does not refresh.

Here is my input field page:

```
<form id="refme"> 

    <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="URL" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="text" id="f_name" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <input type="text" id="s_name" placeholder="Second Name" autocomplete="off"><br>

    <br>
    Reference
    <hr>

    <!-- FINISHED REFERENCE --> 

    <div id="sindex_result">

    </div>  

</form>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#refme input[type=text]').keyup(function() {

        var url = $('#url').val();
        var f_name = $('#f_name').val();
        var s_name = $('#s_name').val();

        if(url === '' && f_name == '' && s_name == ''){}
        else 
        {
            $('#sindex_result').html('');
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://bradleycousins.co.uk/fetch.php",
                method:"post",
                data:{url:url, f_name:f_name, s_name:s_name},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#sindex_result').html(data);
                }
            });
        }




    });
});

</script>
```

Here is my AJAX, 'fetch.php' file:

```
echo $_POST['f_name'] . " " . $_POST['s_name'];
```

This should be pretty simple and currently what I have works. However when used say 4 times in a row then the website goes offline and I get this error "Failed to open page / Safari went offline" This is an issue with all browsers, I checked, so it must be an issue in the code.

Thankyou for any help

==== 
EDIT

A possible solution might be to delay the AJAX Call requests ? I have tried implementing this but nothing outputs at all now,

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var delay = (function () {
    var timer = 0;
    return function (callback, ms) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();


    $('#refme input[type=text]').keyup(function() {

        delay(myKeyUpFunction, 250);

        var url = $('#url').val();
        var f_name = $('#f_name').val();
        var s_name = $('#s_name').val();

        if(url === '' && f_name == '' && s_name == ''){}
        else 
        {
            $('#sindex_result').html('');
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://bradleycousins.co.uk/fetch.php",
                method:"post",
                data:{url:url, f_name:f_name, s_name:s_name},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#sindex_result').html(data);
                }
            });
        }




    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you check if you have any error log in your apache or php folders?

Comment: @MikaA. Unfortunately you can't access the error log with GoDaddy

Comment: Another possible method might be to delay the Ajax requests, I have tied implementing something like this however nothing outputs: http://www.lucadentella.it/en/2013/06/17/javascript-aggiungere-un-ritardo-allevento-keyup/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is you add a slight delay so that when the user types the Ajax call is made 250ms after input has finished.

```
$('#refme input[type=text]').keyup(function() {

    delay(function(){

        var url = $('#url').val();
    var f_name = $('#f_name').val();
    var s_name = $('#s_name').val();

    if(url === '' && f_name == '' && s_name == ''){}
    else 
    {
        $('#sindex_result').html('');
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://bradleycousins.co.uk/fetch.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{url:url, f_name:f_name, s_name:s_name},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#sindex_result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    }, 250);
```